# How to update the Pre-Populated CoreData SQLite file?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I know I can set a Pre-Populated SQLite file as CoreData persist file. But When I update my app version, and the Pre-Populated Data need be updated, I wonder if there has another way to do that except CRUD the new Pre-Populated data by codes after the new version launch.

Comment: Have you looked at using property list files? I've found them relatively easy to manage once you learn to parse the data from the list into your SQLite DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick the pre-populated sqlite file as a source file in the persistentStoreCoordinator but keep in mind that if you update de data, the user generated content will be lost...

Comment: I know, so I think use codes to CURD the newer pre-populated data into old version app is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my project  I have also faced a similar problem. My approach was that.

1. Create 2 configuration in Core Data. One for static data and second for dynamic data.
2. While configuring your persistantCordinator set two separate SQLite files corresponding CoreData configuration.
3. There is not extrac coding effort other than setting up two separate DB in persistantCordinator level. Everything else will be managed by CoreData like. Reading, Writing etc.
4. For static database keep a DATABASE version of your own. When your static data changed increase this database version and in App launch check the existing database version with this new version. If new version is greater copy and replace the existing static database.

With this approach you have the following benefits.

1. You wont lose your dynamic data.
2. You need to change the static database only when there is a change in static data.

Hope this helps.